# is there a sql query I want to get last job_id with the earliest start date

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a sql query I want to get last job_id with the earliest start date.

I have a table named employee

```
employee_id job_id start_date  salary changed_on
123         aaa    2020-08-09  40000. 2020-08-09
123         bbb    2020-08-10  50000. 2020-08-10
123         bbb    2020-08-11  60000. 2020-08-11
456         xxx    2020-08-12  40000  2020-08-12
456         zzz    2020-08-13  50000. 2020-08-13
456         zzz    2020-08-14  60000. 2020-08-14
789         aaa    2020-08-15  70000. 2020-08-15
789         ccc    2020-08-16  80000  2020-08-16
```

expected results

```
employee_id job_id start_date 
123         bbb    2020-08-10
456         zzz    2020-08-13
789         ccc    2020-08-16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use `FIRST_VALUE()` window function to get the latest `job_id` for each  `employee_id` and then use conditional aggregation to get the earliest `start_date` for this `job_id`:

```
SELECT t.employee_id,
       MAX(t.last_job_id) job_id,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t.job_id = t.last_job_id THEN t.start_date END) start_date
FROM (
  SELECT employee_id, job_id, start_date,
         FIRST_VALUE(job_id) OVER (PARTITION BY employee_id ORDER BY start_date DESC) last_job_id
  FROM tablename       
) t  
GROUP BY t.employee_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0106101a1f2cabe19ef647d6eb897d4).

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky.  But in your example, employees never return back to a given job.  If that is the case, you can use aggregation and window functions:

```
select ej.*
from (select employee_id, job_id, min(start_date) as min_start_date,
             row_number() over (partition by employee_id order by max(start_date) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      group by employee_id, job_id
     ) ej
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: How is this correct? It does not even run: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f3204eba21dd5c02ebca1cd9d8de931c